# Resampling and ploting multiple slices from a vtkPolydata

Tags: python, plot, vtk

I have a vtkPolydata with 3D coordinates of the vertex of the grid as points and Temperature at each point stored as point field data. I want to plot the Temperature distribution at different elevations. I am using Python for the operation. I have created a pipeline, and I am able to get the required slice from the vtkPolydata. However, when I rendered it, the plot looked like a scatter plot as shown below:
[image: Plot generated based on the below script]

I want to plot it without any white space in between even when zoomed in. Please help me with this. I think I have to interpolate or create contours from the data, but I have no idea how to do it even after searching for a couple of days.

The code I used to generate the plot is given below.

The vtkPolydata I used to generate the above plot can be downloaded from here: [vtkPolydata](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/df54f405e4221331f37e6aa62d8544d020230113092905/aa8cf9)

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support
import numpy as np

# Load vtkPolydata function
def loadvtp(fname):
    reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
    reader.SetFileName(fname)
    reader.Update()
    data=reader.GetOutput()
    return data

# Load vtkPolydata
polydata=loadvtp("TestPolydata.vtp")

# Set the elevation at which data need to be plotted
ele=12

# %% Clip polydata based on the elevation
# Create plane in +Z to cut the polydata below elevation
plane = vtk.vtkPlane()
plane.SetOrigin(0, 0, ele)
plane.SetNormal(0, 0, 1)

# create polydata clipper
clipper = vtk.vtkClipPolyData()
clipper.SetInputData(polydata)
clipper.SetClipFunction(plane)
clipper.Update()

out_data=clipper.GetOutput()

# Create plane in -Z to cut the polydata above elevation
plane = vtk.vtkPlane()
plane.SetOrigin(0, 0, ele+0.5)
plane.SetNormal(0, 0, -1)
clipper = vtk.vtkClipPolyData()
clipper.SetInputData(out_data)
clipper.SetClipFunction(plane)
clipper.Update()

# Cliped polydata
sampled_data=clipper.GetOutput()

# Get the "Temperature" Array from the polydata
point_scalars = sampled_data.GetPointData().GetArray("Temperature")

# Create a lookup table to map the point field data to colors
lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
lut.SetNumberOfTableValues(2)
lut.SetTableValue(0, 1, 0, 0, 1) # red
lut.SetTableValue(1, 0, 1, 0, 1) # green
lut.Build()

# Create a mapper and actor to display the cliped plane
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(clipper.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetScalarModeToUsePointFieldData()
mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
mapper.SetColorModeToMapScalars()
mapper.SelectColorArray(0)
mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
mapper.SetScalarRange(point_scalars.GetRange())

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

# Create the RenderWindow, Renderer
colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

ren1 = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren1)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

ren1.AddActor(actor)

ren1.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d('Gainsboro'))
renWin.SetSize(650, 650)
renWin.SetWindowName('Test')

style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)

ren1.TwoSidedLightingOff()

ren1.ResetCamera()

renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the workaround. We can use the `vtkPointGaussianMapper`. Refer vtk solved [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Meshes/PointInterpolator/) for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset has no polygons in it, I would create a `vtkImageData` object and slice that.

Quick test in `vedo` gives:

```py
from vedo import *
mtest = load("TestPolydata.vtp")
scalars = mtest.pointdata["Temperature"]
vol = Volume(scalars.reshape([251,251,101]))
vslice = vol.zslice(50).cmap("rainbow").add_scalarbar()
show(vol, vslice, N=2, axes=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try with 'vtkImageData'. If possible can you give me an example of how to implement the pipeline? I have never worked with image data in vtk. Many thanks for your answer.